# delete characters in string with python

Tags: python, string

I would like to delete from a string all the characters from a list.

For example:

```
to_delete = ["w","r"]
word = "word"

word.replace(to_delete,'')

>> od
```

What is the best/fast solution to do it? Is it possible without loops?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "without loops" at all? At some level, you're iterating every character of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest regex:

```
import re

word = "word"
to_delete = ['w', 'r']

re.sub(f"[{''.join({re.escape(i) for i in to_delete})}]", '', word)
```

This will join your characters to replace into a regex set pattern for replacement, takes the word as input, and replaces those characters with empty strings.

Comment: I would just start with `to_delete = "wr"` and save the join step.

Comment: regex is a fun approach, but take care to only try this if the to_delete characters are "nice". If one of them has a special meaning in the context of a regex pattern, things may go wrong. For example, if to_delete is `['w', ']']`, your code will output `word` instead of the desired `ord`.

Comment: @cricket_007 I was working with the OP's starting set

Comment: @Kevin Mostly familiar with .net, wasn't sure if there was a `Regex.Escape`-type method

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, I like the idea of escaping. I think `re.escape` might do the trick.

Comment: @Kevin Found the doc and updated the answer (even though the Q is closed)

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.translate`.

```
>>> word = "word"
>>> to_delete = ["w","r"]
>>> 
>>> trans = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(to_delete))
>>> word.translate(trans)
'od'
```